# Ranger Trino plugin - NullPointerException at RangerTagEnricher

Tags: trino, apache-ranger, apache-atlas

I have build the ***Ranger Trino plugin*** from latest released 2.4.0 Source code [Ranger](https://www.apache.org/dist/ranger/2.4.0/apache-ranger-2.4.0.tar.gz). I have Apache Atlas as tag provider for ranger for tag based policies. I am facing below exception while executing any query from trino when I enable the plugin.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Collection.size()" because "ret" is null
    at org.apache.ranger.plugin.contextenricher.RangerTagEnricher.getEvaluators(RangerTagEnricher.java:753)
    at org.apache.ranger.plugin.contextenricher.RangerTagEnricher.findMatchingTags(RangerTagEnricher.java:680)
    at org.apache.ranger.plugin.contextenricher.RangerTagEnricher.enrich(RangerTagEnricher.java:226)
    at org.apache.ranger.plugin.contextenricher.RangerTagEnricher.enrich(RangerTagEnricher.java:191)
    at org.apache.ranger.plugin.service.RangerDefaultRequestProcessor.enrich(RangerDefaultRequestProcessor.java:114)
    at org.apache.ranger.plugin.service.RangerDefaultRequestProcessor.preProcess(RangerDefaultRequestProcessor.java:99)
    at org.apache.ranger.plugin.policyengine.RangerPolicyEngineImpl.evaluatePolicies(RangerPolicyEngineImpl.java:141)
    at org.apache.ranger.plugin.service.RangerBasePlugin.isAccessAllowed(RangerBasePlugin.java:479)
    at org.apache.ranger.plugin.service.RangerBasePlugin.isAccessAllowed(RangerBasePlugin.java:467)
    at org.apache.ranger.authorization.trino.authorizer.RangerSystemAccessControl.hasPermission(RangerSystemAccessControl.java:792)
    at org.apache.ranger.authorization.trino.authorizer.RangerSystemAccessControl.checkCanImpersonateUser(RangerSystemAccessControl.java:275)
    at org.apache.ranger.authorization.trino.authorizer.RangerSystemAccessControl.checkCanImpersonateUser(RangerSystemAccessControl.java:352)
    at io.trino.security.AccessControlManager.lambda$checkCanImpersonateUser$2(AccessControlManager.java:230)
    at io.trino.security.AccessControlManager.systemAuthorizationCheck(AccessControlManager.java:1339)
    at io.trino.security.AccessControlManager.checkCanImpersonateUser(AccessControlManager.java:230)
    at io.trino.security.ForwardingAccessControl.checkCanImpersonateUser(ForwardingAccessControl.java:58)
    at io.trino.server.QuerySessionSupplier.createSession(QuerySessionSupplier.java:85)
    at io.trino.dispatcher.DispatchManager.createQueryInternal(DispatchManager.java:186)
    at io.trino.dispatcher.DispatchManager.lambda$createQuery$0(DispatchManager.java:161)
    at io.opentelemetry.context.Context.lambda$wrap$1(Context.java:212)
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_419____20230720_204706_2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

My Trino version is - 419